# Once added, Chrome now always prepends www with the domain name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, apartment-gem

I'm using Apartment gem, with Rails 5.0.0.1.

The URL that I'm trying to access is: `lkm.harabiz.com`, and accidentally, I attached `www` with it, and it became: `www.lkm.harabiz.com`, and now I can't access `lkm.harabiz.com`. Each time I try to access: `lkm.harabiz.com`, it enforces the URL: `www.lkm.harabiz.com` on Google Chrome.

The solution may be to delete the URL that starts with `www` from history in Chrome, or something to do with cookies, but what if a novice person accidentally types `www` as my client did, how would he solve the riddle without getting too much into the technical details?

Also, is there a way to redirect `www.lkm.harabiz.com` to `lkm.harabiz.com` through code?

Comment: So have you tried deleting the URL from History?  Usually a response redirect (301) would work, called redirect_to in Ruby I believe

Answer (score 0):

Clearing cache in Chrome should resolve your problem, but you may want to configure your DNS rules to allow `www.lkm.harabiz.com` to resolve to the same address as `lkm.harabiz.com`.